How to add to MongoDB replica set members with TLS connection?
Another "awesome" MongoDB documentaion piece:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/rs.add/
What if member being added has TLS connection?? MongoDB don't bother explaining this.
rs0 [direct: primary] admin> rs.add({host: "mail.giftbutton.com:27017/?tls=true&tlsCAFile=/home/buryj/certsMongoMailer/intermRoot.pem&tlsCertificateKeyFile=/home%2Fburyj/certsMongoMailer/clientKey.pem"})
MongoServerError[InvalidReplicaSetConfig]: member: { host: "mail.giftbutton.com:27017/?tls=true&tlsCAFile=/home/buryj/certsMongoMailer/intermRoot.pem&tlsCertificateKeyFile=/home%2Fburyj/certsMongoMailer/clientKey.pem", _id: 1 } :: caused by :: Did not consume whole string.
rs0 [direct: primary] admin> rs.add({host: "mail.giftbutton.com --tls --tlsCAFile /home/buryj/certsMongoMailer/intermRoot.pem --tlsCertificateKeyFile /home/buryj/certsMongoMailer/clientKey.pem"})
MongoNetworkError: connection 2 to 51.89.216.247:27017 closed
admin> rs.add({host: "mail.giftbutton.com --tls --tlsCAFile=/home/buryj/certsMongoMailer/intermRoot.pem --tlsCertificateKeyFile=/home/buryj/certsMongoMailer/clientKey.pem"})
MongoNetworkError: connection 4 to 51.89.216.247:27017 closed

"connection closed" is when PRIMARY just dies.
Any ideas on how to do it very appreciated!
Edited:
net.clusterFile and security.clusterAuthMode enabled on this replica set member being added (mail.giftbutton.com) only. On PRIMARY (giftbutton.com) these aren't used at the moment - unless I'm told it's necessary.
clientKey.pem cert being used for tls.clusterFile (without privkey):
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----

A part of mongod.conf:
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIpAll: true
  tls:
    mode: requireTLS
    certificateKeyFile: /etc/ssl/openSSL/serverKey.pem
    CAFile: /etc/ssl/openSSL/intermRoot.pem
    clusterFile: /etc/ssl/openSSL/clientKey.pem

security:
  keyFile: /etc/mongodKeyfile
  clusterAuthMode: keyFile


That certificate has X509v3 Extended Key Usage: TLS Web Client Authentication.  You will need to have both client and server to use it for a replica set member, see https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/security-x.509/#member-certificate-requirements

@Joe The documentation is a bit misleading (if not saying "wong"). The certificateKeyFile certificate needs the serverAuth extension, the clusterFile needs the clientAuth extension. I use it like this for years. Of course, if you use the same certificate for both, then it must have both extensions.

All members of your replica set must have the same TLS settings. By default the primary node is not determined, each node can become the primary. Thus, every node in the replica set must be able to connect to each other node and receive connection from each other node.

Missing conf added in PRIMARY and the error on member being added is now different: {"t":{"$date":"2024-12-17T14:11:42.858+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"EXECUTOR", "id":22988,   "ctx":"conn67615","msg":"Error receiving request from client. Ending connection from remote","attr":{"error":{"code":141,"codeName":"SSLHandshakeFailed","errmsg":"SSL peer certificate validation failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain"},"remote":"51.89.216.247:33198","connectionId":67615}}

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

another question opened https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79289644/trying-to-add-mongodb-replica-set-member-with-tls-connection-certificate-error

Is there any reason to open a new question while this first problem isn't yet fixed?

Yes there is. If I edit it all, the question becomes totally disconnected to Wernfried Domscheit's comments, which are super-valuable as always.

You don't specify the TLS options like this:
rs.add({host: "mail.giftbutton.com:27017/?tls=true&tlsCAFile=/home/buryj/certsMongoMailer/intermRoot.pem&tlsCertificateKeyFile=/home%2Fburyj/certsMongoMailer/clientKey.pem"})

TLS options are specified in configuration file (or command line arguments):
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIpAll: true
  tls:
    mode: requireTLS
    certificateKeyFile: .../server.pem
    CAFile: /home/buryj/certsMongoMailer/intermRoot.pem
    clusterFile: /home/buryj/certsMongoMailer/clientKey.pem

security:
    keyFile: ...
    clusterAuthMode: keyFile

The command is the same, i.e.
rs.add({host: "mail.giftbutton.com:27017" })


looking like the certificate used between rs members has wrong purpose   {"t":{"$date":"2024-12-16T17:24:07.400+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"EXECUTOR", "id":22988,   "ctx":"conn86","msg":"Error receiving request from client. Ending connection from remote","attr":{"error":{"code":141,"codeName":"SSLHandshakeFailed","errmsg":"SSL peer certificate validation failed: unsuitable certificate purpose"},"remote":"51.89.216.247:43166","connectionId":86}}

How do you think, I can help you without any certificate or configuration data?

Please edit your question for such additional information, it's very hard to read.

Have a look at Client Certificate Requirements, I think you missed extension keyUsage = digitalSignature
