Trying to add MongoDB replica set member with TLS connection - certificate error
Have a PRIMARY giftbutton.com
Have trying to add mail.giftbutton.com to the replica set
shared the keyFile and the clusterKey.pem file among all
mongo.conf:
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIpAll: true
  tls:
    mode: requireTLS
    certificateKeyFile: /etc/ssl/openSSL/serverKey.pem
    CAFile: /etc/ssl/openSSL/intermRoot.pem
    clusterFile: /etc/ssl/openSSL/clusterKey.pem

security:
  keyFile: /etc/mongodKeyfile
  clusterAuthMode: keyFile

The contents of the clusterKey.pem (without priv key) is:
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----

Have read mongoDB doc:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/security-internal-authentication/

A single Certificate Authority (CA) must issue all x.509 certificates
for the members of a sharded cluster or a replica set.
At least one of the Subject Alternative Name (SAN) entries must match
the server hostname used by other cluster members.
If the certificate used as the clusterFile includes extendedKeyUsage,
the value must include clientAuth.

Seem to satisfy everything, but getting SSL errors:
on giftbutton.com:
{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-17T23:46:05.920+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL_HB",  "id":23974,   "ctx":"ReplCoord-3","msg":"Heartbeat failed after max retries","attr":{"target":"mail.giftbutton.com:27017","maxHeartbeatRetries":2,"error":{"code":6,"codeName":"HostUnreachable","errmsg":"Error connecting to mail.giftbutton.com:27017 (146.59.32.248:27017) :: caused by :: SSL peer certificate validation failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain"}}}

on mail.giftbutton.com:
{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-17T23:47:27.498+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"EXECUTOR", "id":22988,   "ctx":"conn2596","msg":"Error receiving request from client. Ending connection from remote","attr":{"error":{"code":141,"codeName":"SSLHandshakeFailed","errmsg":"SSL peer certificate validation failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain"},"remote":"51.89.216.247:52798","connectionId":2596}}

Any ideas what am I doing wrong is very appreciated!

Were serverKey.pem and clusterKey.pem both signed by intermRoot.pem?  Is intermRoot.pem self-signed?

Most likely a problem with your intermRoot.pem certificate. I guess it miss the Root CA.

Root-CA and interm are made indifidual for each host. Shouldn't SSL certificates be as unique as possible? I made sure I could connect to to each instance individually over TLS first - before creating a replica set, as per MongoDB official advice. I have used root-ca and interm of the primary for generating clusterKey.pem. Now if root-ca and interm certs are the same for each host, isn't it a security compromise?

"Root-CA and interm are made indifidual for each host.", that's wrong, read the documentation you linked: "A single Certificate Authority (CA) must issue all x.509 certificates for the members of a sharded cluster or a replica set." Why do you think SSL certificates should be as unique as possible? Your computer stores less than 100 Root-CA and they are used to verify almost every webserver certificate from the entire internet. Your client certificates are not used for authentication, so why should they be unique?

Corrected. It finally works! Danke schon!!
